# What's the issue with Length()?

Tags: java

I have a java project for uni and this is my code. I have a problem with Length(). Can please anyone help me and spot m mistakes? Thank you in advance.

```
package mytest;

import java.io.File;

public class MyTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File here = new File("");
    File[] contents = here.listFiles();

    for (int counter = 0; counter < contents.Length(); counter++) {
    System.out.println(contents[counter].getName());
    }

    File directory = here getParentDirectory();
    System.out.println("The absolute path is" + directory.getAbsolutePath());
    File[] list = directory.listFiles(); 
    System.out.println("Directrory code contains" + list.Length() + "items\n."); 

    System.out.println("----\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length(); i++) {
        if (list[i].isDirectory())  {
            System.out.println(list[i].getName() + "is a directory with" + list[i].listFiles.Length + "elements"); 

        } else {
            System.out.println(list[i].getName() + "has a size of" + list[i].Length() + "bytes.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Length is an attribute. You have to use `list.length`

Comment: Also what to do you think `list.Length()` does and why do you think so?

Comment: (1) Java is case sensitive so `length()` != `Length()`; (2) there is no `length()` method in arrays, but there is `length` field (notice lack of parenthesis).

Comment: Another issue that I can see is  this line `File directory = here getParentDirectory();` Are you sure this is your code and have you even compiled this??

Comment: I can point out around 2 more issues with your code but seems like you haven't put any effort into it and haven't even compiled the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working on an array you need to use the .length field, there is no method Length().
You can replace in your code .Length() by .length and it should then be fine.

Be also aware however that on the last System.out statement, in the else block of the loop, the array is of type File[], hence each element is a File. A File has a method length() (lower care) which provides the length of the file as a long.

Moreover, in the if block of the loop, the File element of the array provides the method listFiles() (and not a field .listFiles) which is an array and as such, again, it has a field, length, giving you the length of the array.

We hence have:

- An array, providing a field, length
- A File, having a method, length(), for its size
- A method of the File class, listFiles() which returns an array of File

Here is the fully compiling (fixed) code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File here = new File("");
    File[] contents = here.listFiles();

    for (int counter = 0; counter < contents.length; counter++) {
        System.out.println(contents[counter].getName());
    }

    File directory = here.getParentFile();
    System.out.println("The absolute path is" + directory.getAbsolutePath());
    File[] list = directory.listFiles();
    System.out.println("Directrory code contains" + list.length + "items\n.");

    System.out.println("----\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(list[i].getName() + "is a directory with" + list[i].listFiles().length + "elements");

        } else {
            System.out.println(list[i].getName() + "has a size of" + list[i].length() + "bytes.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you haven't read carefully what the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) says:

> Finally, you can use the built-in length property to determine the size of any array.

The proposed example is:

```
System.out.println(anArray.length);
```

In that case, `length` is not a method, instead it's a built-in property of any `array`. Because of that, trying to invoke it will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

For array should use

```
contents.length ;
```

But for string use this

```
 contents.length();
```

Let me first highlight the different way for similar purpose.

`length` --- `arrays` (`int[], double[], String[]`) ---- to know the length of the arrays.

`length()` --- `String` related Object (`String, StringBuilde`r etc)to know the length of the String

Comment: or to avoid another compilation error use `.length` instead of `.Length`.

Comment: Another typo. I guess you mean "Thank you" and not "Think you" ;)

Comment: Yes :) :) :) :)         :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a big distinction between between the .Length(), a class method and the primitive type .length. While using strings, we use the .Length() as a class method. Since Strings are stored in classes in the background. To find the length of an array use the .length; as this actually searches inside the heap memory. If you like some more information on the background reason for this, I suggest you to check the following link.

http://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/what-does-a-java-array-look-like-in-memory/